# UnknownTimeZoneError: 'IST' for apscheduler

Tags: python, timezone, apscheduler

Iam trying adding a job in apscheduler according to the Indian standard time

```
scheduler.add_job('cron',start_date=date, hour=time[0], minute=time[1], id=str(job[0]),timezone='IST')
```

But every time its giving an error UnknownTimeZoneError: 'IST'.
The scheduler is accepting EST,UTC etc. but not IST.

Is IST correct time zone for Indian standard time ? If not how can i schedule a job according to IST ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [comments in source code](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/master/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py#L45) you can pass [`datetime.tzinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo) object to the scheduler:

> :param str|datetime.tzinfo timezone: the default time zone (defaults to the local timezone)

With above in mind you could try following:

```
import datetime
tz = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30))
scheduler.add_job('cron',start_date=date, hour=time[0], minute=time[1], id=str(job[0]),timezone=tz)
```

**Update:** Python 2 doesn't offer concrete implementations of `tzinfo` class but you can [roll your own](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.fromutc):

```
import datetime

class IST(datetime.tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return datetime.timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "IST"

    def dst(self, dt):
        return datetime.timedelta()

tz = IST()
print datetime.datetime.now(tz)
```

Output:

```
2016-12-01 14:33:37.031316+05:30
```

Comment: Is timezone module decrypted in 2.7.12 ? because it is giving me error object has no module timezone. Do i need to import other package ?

Comment: @ketankhandagale Updated for Python 2